# Add GET parameter to all urls from a string in php

Tags: php

I want to get all the html contents of a site and add a custom `GET` param to all URLs.

**My codes:**

```
    function getUrls($string) {
        $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
        preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
        //return (array_reverse($matches[0]));
        return ($matches[0]);
}

function addToUrl($url, $key, $value = null) {
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        if ($query) {
            parse_str($query, $queryParams);
            $queryParams[$key] = $value;
            $url = str_replace("?$query", '?' . http_build_query($queryParams), $url);
        } else {
            $url .= '?' . urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
        }
        return $url;
    }
$s = file_get_contents('http://youtube.com');
$urls = getUrls($s);
foreach($urls as $url)
{
$withParam = addToUrl($url, 'wid', '${wid}');
$s = str_replace($url, $withParam, $s);
}
echo $s;
```

**For example:**

*Before:*

```
$content = '... <a href="http://foo.bar/register.php">register </a> ... <a href="http://foo.bar/login.php?t=1&">login</a> ...';
```

*After:*

```
$content = '... <a href="http://foo.bar/register.php?wid=${wid}">register </a> ... <a href="http://foo.bar/login.php?t=1&wid=${wid}">login</a> ...';
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` ?

Comment: Yes, but str_replace() adds my parameter Several times to the same links

Comment: get page as xml, parse it using [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and alter it as you wish.

Comment: Where are your `str_replace()` codes?

Comment: Do you have only one parameter to append to url? or multiple parameters?

Comment: @Raptor `foreach($urls as $url)
{
$withParam = addToUrl($url, 'wid', '${wid}');
$s = str_replace($url, $withParam, $s);
}`

Comment: @PHPExpert Multiple parameters

Comment: @B.Azizan Please edit your question to paste your codes, and provide how do you fetch the `$urls` array.

Comment: @Raptor operation successfully :)